# BASH Shell not iterating properly

Tags: shell

Here's the code that I have so far. The expected function is for it to print the index of the id and the id itself. Ex. 1 a1.2.6

Here's a link to the ids_alpha.txt file: [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HHY2rpAimZbcPmgDkVqUI3COLThHeit0/view?usp=share_link)

```
function printAlpha() {
    declare -a alpha=$(cat ./bin/data/ids_alpha.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')
    length=${#alpha[@]}

    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++)); do
        echo -ne "${color_normal} $i ${color_off}"
        echo -e "${color_normal} ${alpha[*]} ${color_off}"
    done
   
}
```

The output looks like this: https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0VJtdOXmRaaKPF

I have tried to iterate over the array using many different techniques. However, nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show a relevant snippet of the input file in the question itself, instead of linking to an external resource ([mcve]). For now, I can tell you that `alpha=$(...)` doesn't create an array, but a string. `alpha=($(...))` creates an array, or (better) `readarray`/`mapfile`.

Comment: Also, should `${alpha[*]}` be `${alpha[i]}`?

Comment: All of the above, AND please include your expected output (sans colors, I guess). You should be able to include your current output in the body of your question without using a link to another external resource. Copy/paste the relevant data into your question, and with it still highlighted as *selected*, click the `{}` tool in the Edit menu to get formatting for `code/data/output/errMsgs/etc` .Good luck.
s

Comment: Thank you all, especially @BenjaminW. Ben, thank you for the input you solved my issue! Thank you all again!